# Oracle: list of schedules

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

How to retrieve all the list of schedules of current user? (Oracle 11g r2)

Toad can retrieve it in some way (since it draw them in the objects tree) but I cannot find the view (query) which is allowed to perform by non-sys user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're after [USER_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10755/statviews_1145.htm)?

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_SCHEDULER_SCHEDULES
```

Comment: Almost what I wanted, but there is no `STATE` column there (what I actually am looking for). Btw, why did not they mention about this view at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10739/schedover.htm#sthref3230.

Comment: Yep, it is `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` view. Thanks.

Comment: Argh, 15 minutes is too long to wait until be able to accept answer.